# How set node access for guest?

Tags: users, uri

for example I have a url like:

```
/node/add/feature
```

when I go there as guest, I get `'access denied'`, the access should be changed in the code or in the admin panel? but how can I find the exact place where to make changes by following this url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin panel under `/admin/people/permissions`. The `/node/add/$CONTENT_TYPE` access is controlled under the **Node** section as the *ContentType: Create new content* permission.